# Error committing Oracle tablespace in Docker

Tags: oracle, docker, tablespace

I tried to "docker commit" the tablespace I created on a container that is based on [alexeiled's oracle xe 11g container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g/).

But I got this error:

```
FATA[0027] Error response from daemon: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: write /u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE/usr.dbf: read-only file system
```

Why is it trying to write usr.dbf to a read-only filesystem?

---

Docker command: sudo docker commit d74005e729bd oracle-simou

Docker version: Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef

Host OS: archlinux

Comment: How did you start the container?

Comment: sudo docker run -d -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 -p 49162:8080 alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g

Comment: So you started the container and added a tablespace within it. After that, you tried to commit the changes into a new image?

Comment: @Bohne Yes, this is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that you have enough free disk space for Docker container in docker graph, usually it's `/var/lib/docker/graph`.

If your `/var` space is limited, you can change docker root location by specifying `-g` option

```
-g, --graph="/var/lib/docker"          
Path to use as the root of the Docker runtime
```

Comment: I ended up using wnameless' container (wnameless/docker-oracle-xe-11g) and with your hint I had no problems commiting the tablespace.